# WSO2 ESB 5.0 Cluster Deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am wondering do we need to setup a separate ESB analytics for all the worker nodes. For example, we have one manager node and four worker nodes in high availability cluster. In this case, do we need to setup 5 separate ESB analytics node for all 5 ESB instances or single analytics can be used for all the instances? If we setup 5 analytics instances and it will be difficult to handle. What is the best approach to setup high availability cluster using ESB 5.0? WSO2 documentation does not provide any information about setting up a cluster for ESB 5.0 runtime and analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add separate analytics nodes for ESB runtime cluster worker nodes. As ESB worker nodes manage the whole cluster by itself, just use one analytic instance for statistics.